# Nightwatch.js: window is undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium, reactjs, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to use Nightwatch to test a React application. I'm using React-Router with it.

When running my test with Nightwatch `window` is undefined.

React uses the following snippet to test if the DOM is available:

```
var canUseDOM = !!(
  typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  window.document &&
  window.document.createElement
);
```

From React.js source: [ExecutionEnvironment.js#L16](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/2aeb8a2a6beb00617a4217f7f8284924fa2ad819/src/vendor/core/ExecutionEnvironment.js#L16)

> React-Router expects `canUseDOM` to be true, otherwise it throws an
>   error.

So my test fails because `window` is undefined when running Nightwatch.

Shouldn't `window` be present with selenium webdriver? 
How can I make `window` available?

Comment: Can you put some more details? Where are you executing that check?

Comment: You mean canUseDOM? This is part of React. React-Router throws an error if canUseDOM is false, which it is because window is undefined when running Nightwatch.

Comment: So React is throwing the Error as the WebDriver browser load the page?

Comment: React-Router is throwing the error when trying to do Router.run

Answer (score 11):

From Nighwatch.js (and selenium-webdriver, more specifically) you cannot directly access to the DOM of the client.
You must use the **execute()** function to inject your script :

```
 this.demoTest = function (browser) {
   browser.execute(function(data) {

     var canUseDOM = !!(
       typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
       window.document &&
       window.document.createElement
     );
     alert('canUseDOM ?' + canUseDOM); 

     return true;
   }, [], null);
 };
```

More info in the API : http://nightwatchjs.org/api#execute

Comment: This code works.. But removing that unwanted alert cause execute to hang?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was loading application code in my test without noticing, my nightwatch configuration wasn't quite right. So this is where the error was being raised, because Nightwatch was trying to access `window` in the test code.

Answer (score 0):

window is undefined ..this comes when you use window
function without using process.browser function first
Error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2BdT.png
solution:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kggMb.png