# NightwatchJS: how to loop on elements selected using document.querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, nightwatch.js, selectors-api

I am trying to use document querySelectorAll to select an array of options. I found out that we cant directly use `document.querySelectorAll` as it gives me error

> "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

and instead use it with `browser.execute` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29764295/5346095) answer but still getting undefined. The console statement logs undefined, it should have given me an array of elements instead. If I run this css selector in developer tools, it gives me the array I expect but not here. Any idea if I am doing something wrong?

```
browser.execute(function (data) {
   console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div#question_' + quesNo + ' .answerBlock .answer-value'));
   return true;
},[],null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the way you pass arguments to the `browser.execute`. Try the following:

```
browser.execute((data) =>
{
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div#question_' + arguments[0] + ' .answerBlock .answer-value'));
    return true;
}, [quesNo]);
```

Comment: More or less the same code as I have posted works fine in numerous tests using nightwatch in one of my projects. Your problem is somewhere else.