# using document in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to use:

```
      var newGroups = document.getElementsByTagName("a.group-link")
      var id = newGroups[0].getAttribute('id')
      .click(id)
```

In nightwatch.js - but anytime I try to use '`document`' I get the below error:

```
 ✖ ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nightwatch.js: window is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715293/nightwatch-js-window-is-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it in an execute. This allows you to operate arbitrary javascript.

```
.execute( function() {  
    var newGroups = document.getElementsByTagName("a.group-link")
    var id = newGroups[0].getAttribute('id')
    .click(id)
})
```